# Cannot acces JSON element react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
const [intrebari, setIntrebari] = useState([])
     useEffect(() => {
          let idVar = localStorage.getItem('idVarianta');
          idVar = JSON.parse(idVar)
           axios({
             method: "POST",
             data: {
               idVarianta: idVar,
             },
             withCredentials: true,
             url: "http://localhost:4000/getIntrebari",
           }).then((res) => {
              console.log(res)
              const data = res.data;
           setIntrebari(data);
            console.log('Data has been recieved');
           });
        }, [])
```

which is returning me this:
[image]

How can I access the data? If I try intrebari[0].intrebare it gives me "Cannot access property intrebare of type undefined". Any idea? I tried also to console log intrebari[0] and it's displaying the first element, but when i'm trying to access intrebari[0].intrebare it gives me the error described above.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setIntrebari(data)`, try `setIntrebari(res)`.

Comment: Try putting the axios call in an async function (await the axios call), and await the results in the effect hook.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this. The problem was that the component was rendering before the data was fetching.

```
function getIntrebare() {
      if (intrebari.length !== 0) {
        return intrebari[questionIndex].intrebare;
      }
      return "";
    }
```